# Efficient way to convert hydrogen atoms to neutrons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fusion

Can a hydrogen atom be converted to a neutron with a sufficiently high energy photon?  Or perhaps via a pair of photons having total energy of about 800 keV?  One photon would have an energy of say 430 keV and the other about 370 keV.  The 60 keV difference would give a wavelength roughly equal to the diameter of the hydrogen atom.

So, really, lots of photons creating a high energy field with a "beat frequency" equivalent to ~60 keV.

Comment: With sufficient energy one can make anything that can be made. That's what they do at LHC. Is there an efficient process to convert protons to neutrons? Are supernovas that collapse to neutron stars efficient enough for you?

Comment: "Are core collapse supernovas efficient enough for you?"  I was hoping for something a little less violent.

Comment: I don't see the relevance of having a beat frequency of 60keV, or that when you convert that to a wavelength it is the diameter of the hydrogen atom. I don't think any of that means anything. Besides, referring to a "beat frequency" assumes you have a coherent source, i.e. a 400keV CW free electron laser (good luck with that). Just a beam of 800keV photons makes more sense to me, or just giving the electrons 800keV of kinetic energy. But I have no idea what the resulting cross section for neutron production is.

Comment: A neutron will decay into an electron, a proton, and an antineutrino via the wesk interaction (no photons involved).  Does that tell you anything about your question?

Comment: If you can spare the energy to make a beam of photons of energy 783.3255keV to trigger this rare conversion of Hydrogen atoms into neutrons, which is obviously meant to initiate fusion reactions, then you could have easily just accelerated some protons to 165keV or 600keV that then has a peak in the fusion cross-section. Far less wastage. It is not just about whether you can do something; you also have to consider the costs v.s. cheapness of alternatives.

Comment: First you just need to ionise the hydrogen atom using appropriate ionizing photons then using some  technique convert proton to neutron.

Comment: Perhaps I should've asked what functions as a "watering hole" these days in place of the old Usenet sites sci.physics.fusion and sci.energy

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The mass of the Hydrogen atom or Neutron is much larger than the difference, so a single photon of around 800 keV should be sufficient to convert a Hydrogen atom to a neutron.  It would be really interesting if the required energy to create a neutron could be determined well enough to get an estimate of the mass of the neutrino that would also be created (and ejected).  Unfortunately, the more likely outcome would be ejecting the electron from the Hydrogen atom, so there would be a LOT of background to subtract.

Comment: You statement on neutrinos is already basically in use at KATRIN through studying the endpoint spectrum of tritium beta decay.